# Goland, and PyCharm on the same checked out code repo in a mac

Tags: pycharm, goland

Not sure if this is the right forum to ask the following question:

I use `pycharm` and `goland` both on the same checked out code repo in a Macbook Pro machine running High Sierra. I want to make sure that the temp files between `pycharm` and `goland` are not shared.

The main issue I face is that when I open GoLand or PyCharm it picks up the state from whichever was the last software I was using (i.e. if I was using `pycharms` to do some coding the same set of files will open when I open `GoLand` this is annoying and wastes a lot of time.

What can I modify to ensure that they both maintain separate state.

edit->

It seems like intellij does make this configurable.. based on this link.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Ideally I would like to make it so that the pycharm cache is at `.idea/pycharm` and `.idea/goland`.

Comment: Is using the Python Community plugin in GoLand an option for you in this case?

Or maybe even IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate which would allow you to work with both Go and Python from the same IDE.

Comment: @dlsniper -  I have licenses from my company for both goland and pycharm but not intelliJ IDEA Ultimate.. the goland plugin isn't as great as using goland itself (I believe)... could that also be the case of using goland in intelli J IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: If you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, the Go plugin offers the same functionality as GoLand. Same should be for all other "small" IDEs, like PyCharm, RubyMine, etc. I would recommend checking IDEA Ultimate if you have the time, and then if needed, talk with support about any options for you in this case.

Comment: @dlsniper - well I don't have the license for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, so I guess my original problem statement still stands

Comment: @tsar2512 when you create a project in IntelliJ IDEA you can specify where to store the project metadata, it can be some subdirectory under the project directory that will have another `.idea` subdirectory inside. This way you can open `project\idea\.idea` and `project\pycharm\.idea` independently.

Comment: @CrazyCoder where can we specify this in pycharm and in goland?

Answer (score 1):

This may be difficult as apparently JetBrains use the same configuration infrastructure for multiple products. I know it applies to PyCharm, but I can't check if the same applies to GoLand as I'm not using it. Assuming it does for the rest of the answer.

The per-project settings you're interested in exist in the `.idea` sub-directory from the project dir, used/shared by multiple products. From [What is the .idea folder?](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-):

> The *.idea* folder (hidden on OS X) in the solution root contains
>   IntelliJ’s project specific settings files. These include per-project
>   details such as VCS mapping and run and debug configurations, as well
>   as per-user details, such as currently open files, navigation history
>   and currently selected configuration.

In this context one possible approach to separate the settings for the 2 IDEs would be to make 2 distinct copies of the `.idea` directory to be symlinked as `.idea` as needed, depending on which IDE is being used.

Note that the examples below are based on Linux, things may need some adjusting for Mac.

For example, to run PyCharm:

```
project_dir> rm -f .idea; ln -s .idea_pycharm .idea
project_dir> ls -ld .idea*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username at   13 Apr 19 13:05 .idea -> .idea_pycharm
drwxrwxr-x 2 username at 4096 Apr 19 13:03 .idea_goland
drwxrwxr-x 2 username at 4096 Apr 19 13:03 .idea_pycharm
project_dir> pycharm&
```

And to run GoLand:

```
project_dir> rm -f .idea ; ln -s .idea_goland .idea
project_dir> ls -ld .idea*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username at   12 Apr 19 13:06 .idea -> .idea_goland
drwxrwxr-x 2 username at 4096 Apr 19 13:03 .idea_goland
drwxrwxr-x 2 username at 4096 Apr 19 13:03 .idea_pycharm
project_dir> goland&
```

For even more convenience you could also (as root) rename the respective executables and create wrapper scripts with the original names which would do this automatically (you'd have to invoke them from the respective project directory, tho). Something along these lines:

```
# mv /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh.orig
# vi /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh
# chmod a+x /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh
# cat /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d .idea_pycharm ]; then
    rm -f .idea
    ln -s .idea_pycharm .idea
    ls -ld .idea*
fi

exec /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.6/bin/pycharm.sh.orig "$@"
```

Notes:

- the scheme overall only works when running one IDE at a time, the 1st one will probably be impaired if still running when the 2nd one is launched
- the wrappers are only effective for the project dir in which they're launched, if other projects are open at the same time they  won't have their symlinks updated

Comment: Isn't this overkill it seems like pycharms/goland has a way to change the locations. I just don't know the way to work this since I don't have an example etc. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: @tsar2512 I *think* those do not refer to per-project configurations (i.e. where the settings you're interested in exist), but global IDE configurations, affecting all projects. Unless I missed something :)

Comment: sigh... unfortunately your scheme will work only with me using them one at a time, I usually use both since I have some tiers in golang and some in python... and I do not have IntelliJ IDEA